# How to achieve encrypt and decrypt class object with a file?

Tags: java, encryption

I want to encrypt a file with a class object. The class object describes the file content.

The same set of code was working fine without a padding in Java 1.7 update 51. When I moved to Java 1.7 update 79 which has few security update, I got errors related with encryption padding.

After padding support is added, the class object couldn't be retrieved. `readObject()` in `decryptFile()` throws an `InvalidClassException` for `serialVersionUID` mismatch. The serial Id is same but it couldn't be retrieved correctly.

File encryption and decryption is working without the class object. How to achieve encryption and decryption with class object in a file with padding?

I am using fixed AES key and verified the keys and IV for encryption and decryption.

```
public void encryptFile(FileInfo fileInfo, File inFile, File outFile)
        throws Exception {

    //aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

    aeskeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(aesKey, "AES");
    aesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aeskeySpec);
    aesIV = aesCipher.getIV();

    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(inFile);
    CipherOutputStream os = new CipherOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outFile),
            aesCipher);

    ObjectOutputStream objStream = new ObjectOutputStream(os);

    // File info class object is written
    objStream.writeObject(fileInfo);

    copy(is, os);

    is.close();
    os.close();
}

public void decryptFile(File inFile, File outFile)
        throws Exception {

    //aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

    aeskeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(aesKey, "AES");
    aesCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aeskeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(aesIV));

    CipherInputStream is = new CipherInputStream(new FileInputStream(inFile),
            aesCipher);
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outFile);

    MutableObjectClass objStream = new MutableObjectClass(is, FileInfo.class);
    FileInfo fileInfo = (FileInfo) objStream.readObject();

    //Refer file info object

    copy(is, os);

    is.close();
    os.close();
}
```

MutableObjectClass.java file.

```
class MutableObjectClass extends ObjectInputStream {
    String className;

    public MutableObjectClass(InputStream in, Class<?> cls)
            throws Exception {
        super(in);
        this.className = cls.getName();
    }

    @Override
    protected ObjectStreamClass readClassDescriptor()
            throws Exception {

        ObjectStreamClass cd = super.readClassDescriptor();
        try {
            Field f = cd.getClass().getDeclaredField("name");
            f.setAccessible(true);
            f.set(cd, className);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return cd;
    }
```

Comment: What happens if you use ObjectInputStream instead of the odd subclass?

Comment: I used `MutableObjectClass` as the class will not be available on the same path while decryption. I can move to `ObjectInputStream` if required. When I used `ObjectInputStream` the resulting decrypted file header has few junk bytes, say 16-21 etc.

Comment: It's not clear what it's good for and just complicates reasoning about the code. Try it without and describe what happens.

Comment: `MutableObjectClass` was producing the error, I guess. After moving to `ObjectInputStream` and couple of changes the error was resolved. Thanks for pointing it out. I was overlooking it, as it was working before.

Comment: @pvg Thanks for the suggestion. I can accept your suggestion as an answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, the real answer is 'don't do this'.